# Definition of open/closed sets in terms of boundary

Tags: general-topology

Suppose our carrier set *S* is a metric space.
Say that set *B* is arbitrarily close to set *A* iff, for any point *x* in *A*, for all positive $\epsilon$, there are points of *B* within $\epsilon$ distance of *x*. And say that the *boundary* of $A\subseteq S$ is the set of points in *S* arbitrarily close to *A* and to the complement of *A* in *S*.

My question is: Can we then define $A\subseteq S$ to be *open* iff the intersection of *A* and the boundary of *A* is empty, and define $A\subseteq S$ to be *closed* iff the boundary of *A* is a subset of *A*?

Comment: Yes.................................

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. You can refer to a textbook on general topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; in fact, the result holds for general topological spaces. $\partial A$ is the set of $p \in S$ such that every open neighbourhood $p \in O$ intersects $A$ and its complement $S \setminus A$.

If $A$ is open, then we simply take our open neighbourhood to be $O = A$, which does not intersect $S \setminus A$, therefore every point in $A$ is not in the boundary.

Suppose $A \cap \partial A$ is empty, and let $p \in A$. In particular, $p \not\in \partial A$, so there exists an open neighbourhood $p \in O_p$ that does not intersect $S \setminus A$, or, equivalently, $O_p \subseteq A$. We can write
$$A = \bigcup_{p \in A} O_p$$
so by closure under arbitrary unions, $A$ is open.

An analogous proof holds for metric spaces, replacing neighbourhoods with balls and $\epsilon$'s.